# Trigger.io Backbone and OAuth2 using coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, oauth-2.0, trigger.io

I have a rails app serving data on localhost:3000 using the Doorkeeper gem to provide a secure API

The client is a Trigger.io app I'm testing with my android phone, the Raffler from Railscasts Backbone episodes.

Problems>

1. I have a function that returns the correct oauth token & url for accessing the server. I'm confused as to where I should call that function and how I should store the return value so as it is available to the Collection class before a new collection is created.
2. When the client queries the server it returns 200 and seems to pass the requested object back but my view doesn't give the expected result - it returns zero for the length when it should be three.

To test this out I inputted the url in my browser, copied the returned json object and passed it directly into the function that instantiates @collection in router.coffee/initialize. This gets the desired result in the view.

I tried fetching the json object in Trigger.io's catalyst debugging console, no joy. Fetch returns an object but the length is 0

Not sure how to debug beyond what I've tried, new to coffee/Backbone. Appreciate your help, thanks!

raffler.coffee

```
window.Raffler ?= {
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  init: ->
    new Raffler.Routers.Entries()
    Backbone.history.start()
}

$(document).ready ->
  Raffler.init()
```

entries.coffee

```
class Raffler.Collections.Entries extends Backbone.Collection
  url:  'http://192.168.1.14:3000/api/v1/entries?access_token=022f854...
  initialize: -> # this returns a valid url&token for accessing the server
```

entries_router.coffee

```
class Raffler.Routers.Entries extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Raffler.Collections.Entries()
    @collection.fetch()

  index: ->
    view = new Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').append(view.render().el)
```

entries_index.coffee

```
class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: _.template( $('#item-template').html() )

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('fetch', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(entries: @collection))
    this
```

index.html

```
.....
<head>
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-underscore-template">
        <h1> Raffler </h1>
        <%- entries.length  %>
</script>
</head> etc...
```

---

RE: Problem 1 here's what I'm currently trying:

entries_router.coffee

```
initialize: ->
    @collection = new Raffler.Collections.Entries()
    @collection.fetch()
```

entries.coffee

```
class Raffler.Collections.Entries extends Backbone.Collection
  url: @url
  @url = () -> 
        return "http://192.168.1.14:3000/api/v1/entries?access_token=#{params.access_token}"
```

results in 'url must be specified' error.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods that would solve the first problem. You can set the `url` attribute on the Collection instance. So rather than returning your generated URL, you can do something like:

```
class Raffler.Collections.Entries extends Backbone.Collection
  initialize: (args...) ->
    @url = 'http://192.168.1.14:3000/api/v1/entries?access_token=022f854'
    super(args...)
```

entries = new Raffler.Collections.Entries()
  entries.fetch() # will use the url attribute on the collection instance

You can also specify the URL as a parameter to `fetch`:

```
entries.fetch(url: 'http://somewhereelse.com/') # will use a different URL
```

For the second part, I suspect you're having problems due to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for HTTP requests from JavaScript. The usual solution when using Trigger.io Forge is to use the [forge.requests](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html) module to make cross domain requests, a simple way to populate your collection would be:

```
entries = new Raffler.Collections.Entries()

forge.requests.ajax(
  url: 'http://192.168.1.14:3000/api/v1/entries?access_token=022f854'
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'json'
  success: (data) ->
    entries.reset(data)
  error: (e) ->
    forge.logging.error("Failed to get entries: #{e.message}")
)
```

A more useful way might be to override [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to back onto `forge.requests.ajax`. This is probably just a case of changing the last line of `Backbone.sync` from `$.ajax` as the two APIs are pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks Monk, Yeah I've used forge's ajax api to access my server endpoints and it all works pretty well, but like you said I was wondering could I integrate it with backone.sync. I'll give it shot

Comment: RE: url I'm not sure how to instantiate an object for it that will be available when the collection itself is instantiated. At the moment I created the Raffer ?{} namespace and call init-> which creates a new router and starts the history, the router then instantiates the collection which triggers the no url error. Where and how would you set the url variable? I've been trying url = ()-> in the Collections Class

Comment: RE: overriding sync would you be able to provide a snippet of the line in question as you would see it, I've tried to override the sync method and it's throwing an error, thanks - very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone - https://github.com/martindavis/trigger-backbone.sync